# Can i suppress error message from fetch.pm in Perl

Tags: perl, teamcity, fetch

When using Fetch to download a url from Teamcity I get a Fetch failed! error. But the download of the file actually works.

They have recently changed permissions of our Teamcity server so i've to use a username and password when obtaining the URL of the file to download. I'm just wondering if this is causing an issue with fetch's validation of the Gateway, but as I can download the file. Is there a way to suppress this error or just downgrade it to a warning?

```
Perl Code:
my $ff = File::Fetch->new(uri => "$uri"); 
my $where = $ff->fetch   ( to => "$DOWNLOAD_LOCATION" );
print Dumper($ff);

Output:    
Fetch failed! HTTP response: 502 Bad Gateway [502 notresolvable] at         
<path>\myfile.pl line 249.

Dumper Output:
$VAR1 = bless( {'vol' => '',
                'file_default' => 'file_default',
                '_error_msg' => 'Fetch failed! HTTP response: 502 Bad Gateway [502 notresolvable]',
                'file' => 'myfilename.zip',
                'scheme' => 'http',
                'path' => '/repository/download/buildlabel/1042086:id/',
                '_error_msg_long' => 'Fetch failed! HTTP response: 502 Bad    Gateway [502 notresolvable] at C:/Perl/lib/File/Fetch.pm line 598.
```

Comment: So the script doesn't exit?  Then you _are_ getting a warning?  You can control it by localizing the `$SIG{__WARN__}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is a warning (message) being printed to `STDERR`. Apparently you are not getting a `die` or the program would exit. You can control the process of printing the message by setting the `$SIG{__WARN__}` hook, best localized in a block.

```
my $where;

FETCH: {

    local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { 
        print "WARN: @_";        # or whatever appropriate
    };

    $where = $ff->fetch   ( to => "$DOWNLOAD_LOCATION" );    
};
```

or

```
my $where = do { 
    local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { print "WARN: @_" };
    $ff->fetch;
};
```

The signal's disposition – to print to `STDERR` – is restored outside of the block, which is what `local` provides.  See [this in perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Temporary-Values-via-local%28%29), in particular text right after "*Synopsis*". You can also do that manually by saying `$SIG{__WARN__} = 'DEFAULT';` once you are done.

See [warn](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/warn.html)

> No message is printed if there is a `$SIG{__WARN__}` handler installed. It is the handler's responsibility to deal with the message as it sees fit (like, for instance, converting it into a die).

Also see `%SIG` entry [in perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables)

> The routine indicated by `$SIG{__WARN__}` is called when a warning message is about to be printed. The warning message is passed as the first argument. The presence of a `__WARN__` hook causes the ordinary printing of warnings to STDERR to be suppressed.

---

While deciding what to call an "error" and what a "warning" may be a bit arbitrary, it appears clear that your program only emits a message to `STDERR` and continues. Then the above should suffice.

If you were being hit by a `die` then you could wrap the code in [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html).

Comment: @duskwuff  Thank you for the edit. I copied from docs and never noticed that (the ciritical) parts were unformatted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Fetch#File::Fetch::WARN) explains, just set

```
$File::Fetch::WARN = 0;
```

to suppress warnings.