# perl: catching GetOptions when something fails

Tags: perl, getopt

Using `Getopt::Long`, I want to capture any failures from `GetOptions` and, rather than printing them to STDOUT/STDERR, I want to print out a Usage string and exit the script.  I tried wrapping the call to `GetOptions` in a `Try::Tiny` `try/catch` block, but it doesn't get caught.  I'm not sure what's going on behind the scenes here.

How can I capture a failure in `GetOptions`, prevent it from printing, and print my own usage statement instead?

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44011471/4653379) (for instance), on `__WARN__` hooks.  But I also leave `Getopt`'s messages, as they are good, and add my own.

Answer (score 2):

It uses `warn`, so you could use `$SIG{__WARN__}`. I would say it's better to provide a usage statement in addition to the specific error found by `GetOptions`.

```
sub usage {
   my $prog = basename($0);
   if (my ($msg) = @_) {
      chomp($msg);
      warn("$msg\n");
   }

   warn("Try `$prog --help' for more information.\n");
   exit(1);
}

sub help {
   my $prog = basename($0);
   print(<<"__EOS__");
usage: $prog [options] [--] {foo} {bar}
       $prog --help

Options:
   ...
__EOS__
   exit(0);
}

sub parse_args {
   GetOptions(
      'h|?|help' => \&help,
      ...,
   )
      or usage();

   @ARGV == 2
      or usage("Too many arguments.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I do:

```
eval {
    local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { die $_[0] };

    GetOptions( \%opt, ... );
  };

if ( $@ ) {
  ...
}
```